# how to create laravel migration for postgresql array data type

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-migrations

I have the following laravel migration **up** method

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('mobile')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        // $table->string('sports');
        $table->date('dob');
        $table->string('height');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN sports TYPE text[] AFTER password');
}
```

when I run migration it will show **SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "text"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN sports TYPE text[] AFTER passwo...
^ (SQL: ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN sports TYPE text[] AFTER password)**. I don't know what's a problem there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try your Sql statement like this:

```
 DB::statement('alter table users alter sports drop default');
    DB::statement('alter table users alter sports type text[] using array[sports]');
    DB::statement("alter table users alter sports set default '{}'");
```

Comment: it is working but it will add column at last, i need it after 'password' column only

Comment: what about: DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN sports TEXT[]');

Comment: or DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users MODIFY COLUMN sports TEXT[]');

Comment: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "MODIFY"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE users MODIFY COLUMN sports TEXT[]
                          ^ (SQL: ALTER TABLE users MODIFY COLUMN sports TEXT[])

Comment: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TEXT"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN sports TEXT[]
                                              ^ (SQL: ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN sports TEXT[])

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_alter_column.asp

Comment: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "MODIFY"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE users MODIFY sports TEXT[]
                          ^ (SQL: ALTER TABLE users MODIFY sports TEXT[])

Comment: I have updated my answer, see the current solution

Comment: OT (sort of): a common mistake is to believe we "need" a relational model to follow a specific human order, like in the physical world. We don't. Unless one is relying on processing database objects from the information schema based on a pre determined order (which is also a mistake), dropping a column and then adding it back again to the table at the end won't impact database functionality or performance. This is related to the common advise to avoid "SELECT * FROM" style. Let the database take care of the inner details and focus on the logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // ...
        $table->string('sports');
        // ...
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN sports TYPE text[] USING ARRAY[sports]');
}
```